# Function in outer() to identify exact equality

Tags: r

Please run this code:

```
list2env(list(df1 = iris, df2 = iris, df3 = CO2, df4 = CO2, df5 = cars), .GlobalEnv)
```

It will create 5 data.frame objects **df1~df5** into your workspace.

- **df1** = **df2** = `iris`
- **df3** = **df4** = `CO2`
- **df5** = `cars` (They are the built-in datasets in R.)

Now I'm trying to identify which pair of objects is equal using `identical()` or `all.equal()`. First I pick up the object names:

```
name_df <- ls(pattern = "^df") # [1] "df1" "df2" "df3" "df4" "df5"
```

And the **expected output** is a table like this:

```
#       df1    df2    df3    df4    df5
# df1   TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# df2   TRUE   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# df3   FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
# df4   FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
# df5   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

But actually, I think I don't need to use `tidyverse`. The base function `outer()` might be more suitable in this case. However, the following code always gets an error no matter how I revise it.(I have tried `Vectorize()` each argument of `identical()` but it still doesn't work)

```
outer(name_df, name_df, function(x, y){
  identical(get(x), get(y))
# Vectorize(identical)(get(x), get(y))
})
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap with `Vectorize` on the function

```
f1 <- Vectorize(function(x, y) identical(get(x), get(y)))
outer(name_df, name_df, f1)
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` with `crossing`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(name_df, name_df) %>% 
   mutate(Equal = map2_lgl(mget(name_df, envir = .GlobalEnv), 
                          mget(name_df1, envir = .GlobalEnv), 
             identical)) %>% 
   spread(name_df1, Equal) %>%
   column_to_rownames('name_df')
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't think of that `Vectorize` should be put outside the function. Thanks for the help.